# in Nokogiri how would I select an element with an empty class attribute?

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

I've looked everywhere for this but I cannot seem to find the answer on how to select elements with an empty class attribute in Ruby's web scraping api Nokogiri?

In css the answer seems quite straight forward but in nokogiri, I have not been able to find the answer. Below is an example of the html that I'd like to target using nokogiri:

```
<td class="">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# encoding: UTF-8 
require 'nokogiri'

web = '<a class="ok">selected</a>'


p Nokogiri::HTML(web).xpath('//a[@class="ok"]').text
#=> selected

web = '<a class="">selected</a>'


p Nokogiri::HTML(web).xpath('//a[@class=""]').text
#=> selected
```

I can select empty class elements by this way, maybe you can try it, do you check you have other syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

The DOM-selector syntax goes deeper than just element names, classes, and ids. You can also match certain attribute values, and `class` is just another attribute.

To select all `td` where the class is an empty string:

```
"td[class='']"
```

Note that this is different than selecting `td` that *dont* have a class attribute set. In that case, you could use:

```
"td:not([class])"
```

It sounds like the HTML doesn't belong to you, though, so I'd take a different approach. If you're using Chrome, find the element in the browser inspector's HTML tree, right click and click copy => selector. Then paste; you have a unique selector to access the element.

This is made even more complicated, though, by the fact that Nokogiri doesn't run Javacript. So you have no guarantee that the DOM in the browser inspector is the same as the one referenced by Nokogiri. In that case, you'd need to look at the original page source and see if the structure is the same.

All in all, you're going to have the easiest time scraping other people's pages if you use an automated browser like Selenium that can run JS.